# move JRE during update procedure

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

I have an Java/Eclipse application and want to create an update mechanism.
The JRE is in the Eclipse installation directory (Application/JRE) and I don't want to use the Equinox p2 mechanism.

I will have to do the following steps:

- check if update is needed
- download and unpack update (including JRE)
- backup old installation (in separated directory)
- move unpacked application to installation directory
- start application

Now I fear that I won't be able to move the JRE because of the still running VM.
I also think shutdown hooks will probably not work since this also happens on the running VM.

Does anybody have experience with a use case like this, what would be the best practice to accomplish the move of the JRE?
Create a .bat file and run it before exit?

Comment: You say you don't want it, but the obvious answer is to use p2. What's your reason for avoiding it?

Comment: For what I found on the internet, p2 is also not capable of updating the JRE: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=300812

Comment: The comment at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=300812#c25 says that you could use a touchpoint to refer to a different folder that contains the updated JRE. But that does leave the old one(s) lying around, though.

Comment: Updating to a clean installation is one of the reasons we switched from p2 to our own update mechanism. The old bundles were also kept in the plugins directory, maybe there would be a handling for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution, there are some utility classes calls but all in all I think it's clear what is done:

The key part is:

> Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"update process\" " + batFile);

where the batch file is started in an independent process, the batch file itself then does all the copying.

```
/**
 * update the client installation, downloading update from server
 *
 * @return true if the update was successful
 * @throws InvocationTargetException
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
protected boolean updateClient() throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
    final File installDirectory = PathUtil.convertToFile(Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL());
    if (!installDirectory.canWrite()) {
        MessageDialog.openError(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), "Keine Schreibrechte",
                "Keine Schreibrechte auf dem Installationsverzeichnis, Update kann nicht durchgeführt werden. Bitte benachrichtigen Sie einen Administrator.");
        return false;
    }

    ProgressMonitorDialog dialog = new ProgressMonitorDialog(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell());
    dialog.run(false, false, new IRunnableWithProgress() {
        @Override
        public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
            try {
                monitor.setTaskName("Update wird heruntergeladen");

                File updateDirectory = Files.createTempDirectory("update_").toFile(); //$NON-NLS-1$
                File outputDirectory = new File(updateDirectory, "PackageClient"); //$NON-NLS-1$

                String arch = System.getProperty("osgi.arch"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                HttpURLConnection connection = ConnectionUtil.openConnection("update/PackageClient_" + arch + ".zip"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$

                logger.info("download update from {}", connection.getURL()); //$NON-NLS-1$
                logger.info("unpack update to {}", outputDirectory); //$NON-NLS-1$

                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
                ZipUtil.unzipToDirectory(outputDirectory, in, monitor);
                in.close();

                // write batch file for later execution, since not able to update running application and JRE
                String launcher = System.getProperty("eclipse.launcher"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                File batFile = new File(updateDirectory, "update.bat"); //$NON-NLS-1$

                // create batch file which will create backup, delete original installation, copy update and start application
                String batchContent = String.format(
                        "xcopy \"%1$s\" \"%2$s\\backup\" /i /s /h /e /y\r\n" //$NON-NLS-1$
                                + "FOR /D %%%%p IN (\"%1$s\\*.*\") DO rmdir \"%%%%p\" /s /q\r\ndel /q \"%1$s\\*.*\"\r\n" //$NON-NLS-1$
                                + "xcopy \"%3$s\" \"%1$s\" /i /s /h /e /y\r\ncd \"%1$s\"\r\n" + "start \"\" \"%4$s\"\r\n" //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
                                + "start /MIN \"\" cmd /c rmdir \"%2$s\" /s /q exit\r\nexit", //$NON-NLS-1$
                        installDirectory, updateDirectory, outputDirectory, launcher);
                FileUtil.writeFile(batFile, batchContent);

                logger.info("launching update batch file {}", batFile); //$NON-NLS-1$

                // start update batch file in independent process
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"update process\" " + batFile); //$NON-NLS-1$
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new InvocationTargetException(e);
            }
        }
    });

    return dialog.getReturnCode() == Window.OK;
}
```

Here an example of the batch file that is created:

```
xcopy "D:\temp\test\eclipse" "D:\temp\fdo\update_3081617184889033760\backup" /i /s /h /e /y
FOR /D %%p IN ("D:\temp\test\eclipse\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
del /q "D:\temp\test\eclipse\*.*"
xcopy "D:\temp\fdo\update_3081617184889033760\PackageClient" "D:\temp\test\eclipse" /i /s /h /e /y
cd "D:\temp\test\eclipse"
start "" "D:\temp\test\eclipse\Application.exe"
start /MIN "" cmd /c rmdir "D:\temp\fdo\update_3081617184889033760" /s /q exit
exit
```